# std::regex_match and lazy quantifier with strange behavior

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, non-greedy

I know that:
**Lazy quantifier matches: As Few As Possible (shortest match)**

Also know that the constructor:

```
basic_regex( ...,
            flag_type f = std::regex_constants::ECMAScript );
```

And:
`ECMAScript` supports **non-greedy** matches,
and the `ECMAScript` regex `"<tag[^>]*>.*?</tag>"`
would match only until the **first** closing tag ...
[en.cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/syntax_option_type)

And:
At most one grammar option must be chosen out of `ECMAScript`,
`basic`, `extended`, `awk`, `grep`, `egrep`. If no grammar is chosen,
`ECMAScript` is assumed to be selected ...
[en.cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex)

And:
Note that `regex_match` will only successfully match a regular expression to an entire character sequence, whereas `std::regex_search` will successfully match subsequences...[std::regex_match](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match)

---

Here is my code: + [Live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/FRlEP4a3qKpzVcrh)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main(){

        std::string string( "s/one/two/three/four/five/six/g" );
        std::match_results< std::string::const_iterator > match;
        std::basic_regex< char > regex ( "s?/.+?/g?" );  // non-greedy
        bool test = false;

        using namespace std::regex_constants;

        // okay recognize the lazy operator .+?
        test = std::regex_search( string, match, regex );
        std::cout << test << '\n';
        std::cout << match.str() << '\n';
        // does not recognize the lazy operator .+?
        test = std::regex_match( string, match, regex, match_not_bol | match_not_eol );
        std::cout << test << '\n';
        std::cout << match.str() << '\n';
}
```

and the output:

> ```
> 1
> s/one/
> 1
> s/one/two/three/four/five/six/g
>
> Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.008 s
> Press ENTER to continue.
> ```

---

`std::regex_match` should not match anything and it should return `0` with **non-greedy** quantifier `.+?`

In fact, here, the **non-greedy** `.+?` quantifier has the same meaning as **greedy** one, and both `/.+?/` and `/.+/` match the same string. They are different patterns.
**So the problem is why the question mark is ignored?**

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8FRd9Q/1)

Fast test:

```
$ echo 's/one/two/three/four/five/six/g' | perl -lne '/s?\/.+?\/g?/ && print $&'
$ s/one/
$
$ echo 's/one/two/three/four/five/six/g' | perl -lne '/s?\/.+\/g?/ && print $&'
$ s/one/two/three/four/five/six/g
```

---

**NOTE**
this regex: `std::basic_regex< char > regex ( "s?/.+?/g?" );` non-greedy
and this  : `std::basic_regex< char > regex ( "s?/.+/g?" );`  greedy
have the same output with `std::regex_match`. Still both match the entire of the string!
But with `std::regex_search` have the different output.
Also `s?` or `g?` does not matter and with `/.*?/` still matches the entire of the string!

**More Detail**

```
g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 6.2.0-3ubuntu11~16.04) 6.2.0 20160901
```

Comment: There is no issue here, the results are expected. Note that the "Lazy quantifier matches: As Few As Possible (shortest match)" is a wrong statement as lazy quantifier just makes a regex engine grab the mstching text up to the leftmost occurrence of the subsequent subpattern(s), it does not yield the shortest matches.And a dot matches any symbol other than line break, so `^.*?$` is the same as `^.*$`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. I already have seen your other answers about `lazy-quantifier` but here it does not **make sense** to me why `?` is ignored? I turned on the flags `match_not_bol | match_not_eol` but still it is ignored!

Comment: The quantifiers are never *ignored*. Moreover, it is not `?`, it is `+?`. sln already informed you that `regex_match` requires a full string match (=anchors the match at start and end of string), and as `.`  matches any char, the `.+?` just matches up to the first obligatory subpattern on the right. [Here is the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jpgcck/2). When you use `regex_search`, the results would [look like this](https://regex101.com/r/StYFOS/1).

Comment: The *`std::regex_match` should not match anything* is wrong just because the `^s?/.+?/g?$` matches the first `s`, then `/` then any 0+ chars as few as possible up to the first `/` that may be followed by `g` (not necessarily) that is at the end of the string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. You are **right**. If I use `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end of the **regex** it matches **the whole** string. but I put the flags `match_not_bol | match_not_eol`  and it still matches! **if the flags is ignored** then why ever does it exist? or have created?

Comment: These flags do not unanchor the pattern, they have no effect on `regex_match`. If you go to the `regex_match` reference page, you will see it is repeated several times: the pattern must match the entire char sequence. The flags are only meant to make `^` and `$` match at the very start/end of string with `regex_search`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any inconsistency. `regex_match` tries to match the whole string, so `s?/.+?/g?` lazily expands till the whole string is covered.

These "diagrams" (for `regex_search`) will hopefully help to get the idea of greediness:

```
Non-greedy:

a.*?a: ababa
a|.*?a: a|baba
a.*?|a: a|baba  # ok, let's try .*? == "" first
# can't go further, backtracking
a.*?|a: ab|aba  # lets try .*? == "b" now
a.*?a|: aba|ba
# If the regex were a.*?a$, there would be two extra backtracking
# steps such that .*? == "bab".

Greedy:

a.*?a: ababa
a|.*a: a|baba
a.*|a: ababa|  # try .* == "baba" first
# backtrack
a.*|a: abab|a  # try .* == "bab" now
a.*a|: ababa|
```

And `regex_match( abc )` is like `regex_search( ^abc$ )` in this case.

Comment: Way does it **expand** whereas I use **non-greedy**?

Comment: @k-five The reason is, regex match has implicit BOS/EOS anchors `^<your regex>$`, the engine will always prefer to match over non-match. Non-greedy is just a suggestion, not a reality.

Comment: @sln I know about that. with `match_not_eol | match_not_bol` flags still matches!

Comment: @KirillBulygin I know about that. with `match_not_bol | match_not_eol`  flags still matches!

Comment: @k-five I think the flags `match_not_bol | match_not_eol` are ignored for regex_match. Better check the Boost regex docs. Also, like said, regex_match can _only_ match the whole string. The regex `.+?` actually gives it a way to do that.