# Match 3 and 4 delimiters and between them; not less not more

Tags: regex

I have a `command-line` program that its first argument `( = argv[ 1 ] )` is a regex pattern.

`./program 's/one-or-more/anything/gi/digit-digit'`

So I need a regex to check if the entered input from user **is correct or not**. This regex can be solve easily but since I use [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) library and [`std::regex_match`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match) and this function **by default** puts **begin** and **end** assertion (`^` and `$`) at the given string, so the **nan-greedy** quantifier is ignored.

Let me clarify the subject. If I want to match `/anything/` then I can use `/.*?/` but `std::regex_match` considers this pattern as `^/.*?/$` and therefore if the user enters:  `/anything/anything/anyhting/` the `std::regex_match` still returns **true** whereas the input-pattern **is not correct**. The `std::regex_match` only returns **true** or **false** and the expected pattern form the user can only be a text according to the pattern. Since the pattern is various, here, I can not provide you all possibilities, but I give you some example.
**Should be match**

```
/.//
s/.//
/.//g
/.//i
/././gi
/one-or-more/anything/
/one-or-more/anything/g/3
/one-or-more/anything/i
/one-or-more/anything/gi/99
s/one-or-more/anything/g/4
s/one-or-more/anything/i
s/one-or-more/anything/gi/54

and anything look like this pattern
```

---

Rules:

1. delimiters are `/|@#`
2. `s` letter at the beginning and `g`, `i` and 2 digits at the end are optional
3. `std::regex_match` function returns **true** if the entire target character sequence can be match, otherwise return **false**
4. between first and second delimiter can be **one-or-more** `+`
5. between second and third delimiter can be **zero-or-more** `*`
6. between third and fourth can be **g** or **i**
7. At least **3** delimiter should be match `/.//` not less so `/./` should not be match
8. [ECMAScript 262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) is allowed for the pattern

---

**NOTE**

- May you would need to see may question about `std::regex_match`:
  [std::regex_match and lazy quantifier with strange
  behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422778/stdregex-match-and-lazy-quantifier-with-strange-behavior)
- I no need any C++ code, I just need a pattern.
- Do not try `d?([/|@#]).+?\1.*?\1[gi]?[gi]?\1?d?\d?\d?`. It fails.
- My attempt so far: [`^(?!s?([/|@#]).+?\1.*?\1.*?\1)s?([/|@#]).+?\2.*?\2[gi]?[gi]?\d?\d?$`](https://regex101.com/r/3SC0l8/6)
- If you are willing to try, you should put `^` and `$` around your pattern

---

If you need more details please comment me, and I will update the question.
Thanks.

Comment: I suspect I am missing something here, and I haven't allowed for different delimiters yet - but would this not work? https://regex101.com/r/Zb6DXL/1

Comment: @Theo Please wait that I can test it. It seem look like correct

Comment: @Theo **NO**  your pattern matches one or more digit at the end. test it with `.../gi/33333333333` and so on

Comment: ok so the `\d+` will be to blame we can swap this for `\d{1,2}` to only match one or two - see updated version: https://regex101.com/r/Zb6DXL/2 - If this works I will provide answer and explain the regex a bit

Comment: @Theo I need to update the my question I am messing some rule

Comment: OK I will wait for update - I did just make a version of this that supports different delimiters: https://regex101.com/r/fllvUU/1

Comment: @Theo. Many thanks but `/./` should not be match can you provide  new one with support rule 7

Comment: Can you update your list of what should match?

Comment: @Theo Please see [link](https://regex101.com/r/Zb6DXL/3) take a look at **should not be match**

Comment: This has become trickier with that additional rule - I'm not giving up but it may take me a bit longer to respond

Comment: @Theo Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this regular expression:

```
^s?([/|@#])((?!\1).)+\1((?!\1).)*\1((gi?|ig)(\1\d\d?)?|i)?$
```

See [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Zb6DXL/10)

Note how this also rejects these cases:

```
///anything/
/./anything/gg
/./anything/ii
/./anything/i/12
```

#### How it works:

Some explanation of the parts that are different:

- `((?!\1).)`: this will match any character that is not the delimiter. This way you are sure you can keep track of the exact number of delimiters used. You can this way also prevent that the first character after the first delimiter, is again that delimiter, which should not be allowed.
- `(gi?|ig)`: matches any of the valid modifier combinations, except a sole `i`, which is treated separately. So this also excludes `gg` and `ii` as valid character sequences.
- `(\1\d\d?)?`: optionally allows for an extra delimiter (after a `g` modifier -- see previous) to be added with one or two digits following it.
- `(     |i)?`: for the case there is no `g` modifier present, but just the `i` or none: then no digits are allowed to follow.

Comment: Many thanks but it should not match `s/.///33`  at least **g** is needed [link](https://regex101.com/r/Zb6DXL/6)

Comment: I had already updated my regex and answer to deal with that. Please check again.

Comment: Okay I did a fast test and it worked. Please add more detail that **how it works** and I after full test it with my program accept your answer

Comment: Added more detail.

Comment: Why not? In that case `gi` is interpreted as the replacement string, not as the modifiers. It is essentially one of the patterns you want to accept: `s/one-or-more/anything/33`, where *anything* happens to be `gi`.

Comment: I know but here `s/./gi/33` the **gi** is `anything` and **33** is put instead of **gi** flags

Comment: How does it differ from `s/one-or-more/anything/33` which you want to accept?

Comment: I am so sorry but as you see this is not a simple pattern to guess all cases with that I made a mistake

Comment: So now you don't want to have digits at the end, *unless* there is also a modifier? Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes. the digits are for **index** substitution and it allows if there is a **g**  flag at least

Comment: So the digits are also not allowed when there is just an `i` modifier and not a `g` modifier?

Comment: Yes. if you can match only **g** okay it is better

Comment: OK, see the "updated rules" section I added to my answer. If OK, I will integrate it into the first part of my answer. Oops, had to update the regex link as well: https://regex101.com/r/Zb6DXL/9

Comment: okay, It takes me a few minutes to test all possibilities. Many thanks to you. I will comment you if I need. then you can edit your answer for last time

Comment: It is better more than I thought at first. Thank you so much and excuse me if I annoyed you. And a favor to me -- can you introduce to me a good book on learning regex to read, also at level average or upper

Comment: I don't really have a book to suggest: I just learned by doing.

Comment: @trincot this doesnt seem to match `s/one-or-more/anything/33`

Comment: Indeed, Theo, the rules changed. See the comments in this thread.

Comment: @k-five, I consolidated the edits into the final answer. For an interactive tutorial on the basics (no look around), have a look at https://regexone.com, for a more comprehensive reference, have a look at this book: https://www.princeton.edu/~mlovett/reference/Regular-Expressions.pdf

Comment: @trincot ok fair enough, I was busy trying to make it support that exact scenario, I will delete my answer :(

Comment: @trincot. Hi, I called you may you can help me with the same **problem** that I have on window. [Here I asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42627957/the-same-regex-but-different-results-on-linux-and-windows-only-c)

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky one, but I took the challenge - here is what I have ended up with:

[`^s?([\/|@#])(?:(?!\1).)+\1(?:(?!\1).)*\1(?:i|(?:gi?|ig)(\1\d{1,2})?)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/orl1sZ/2)

Pattern breakdown:

- `^` matches start of string
- `s?` matches an optional 's' character
- `([\/|@#])` matches the delimeter characters and captures as group `1`
- `(?:(?!\1).)+` matches anything other than the delimiter character one or more times (uses negative lookahead to make sure that the character isn't the delimiter matched in group `1`)
- `\1` matches the delimiter character captured in group `1`
- `(?:(?!\1).)*` matches anything other than the delimiter character zero or more times
- `\1` matches the delimiter character captured in group `1`
- `(?:` starts a new group

  - `i` matches the `i` character
  - `|` *or*
  - `(?:gi?|ig)` matches either `g`, `gi`, or `ig`
  - `(\1\d{1,2})?` followed by an optional extra delimiter and 0-9 once or twice
- `)?` closes group and makes it optional
- `$` matches end of string

I have used non capturing groups throughout - these are groups that start `?:`

Comment: We are here to learn not just downvote or upvote. Since I can learn a little thing from you answer it is worth it to me

Comment: OK - I've added a disclaimer just to be clear it doesn't cope with your current scenario; but glad if it helps you learn.

Comment: The answer **trincot** is correct as I wanted. However thanks for your attempt. Just to mention, it should not match `s/./g/i/33` but your pattern matches it. The digits are allowed if there is a `g` flag.

Comment: Could not bear to leave an incorrect answer so have updated

Comment: Okay looks good. You do your best. Just remove `/m` at the end of your pattern

Comment: @k-five thank you yes I have fixed, I had left in from my testing, but of course you are only testing one item