# the same regex but different results on Linux and Windows only C++

Tags: c++, regex, windows

I have this pattern for my command-line program:
[`^s?([/|@#])(?:(?!\1).)+\1(?:(?!\1).)*\1(?:(?:gi?|ig)?(?:\1\d\d?)?|i)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/Zb6DXL/10)
based on `ECMAScript 262` for C++.

This is a special pattern to check if the user have entered a correct command or not.
It is a test against a string like this:
`optional-s/one-or-more/anything/optional-g-or-i/optional-2-digits`

[Here is my previous question why I need this pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460667/match-3-and-4-delimiters-and-between-them-not-less-not-more).
 Although it works fine on Linux,
but does not work on Windows. Also I know about line-break on the two machines and I have
read this: [How are \n and \r handled differently on Linux and Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/374028/how-are-n-and-r-handled-differently-on-linux-and-windows)

My program does work with any files, it only gets the first argument of the command-line `argv[ 1 ]` and the `std::regex_match` tests if the **entered-user-synopsis** is correct or not.
Like: `./program 's/one/two/' *.txt` that simply renames **one** to **two** for all **txt** files

the C++ code:

```
std::string argv_1 = argv[ 1 ]; // => s/one/two/
bool rename_is_correct =
std::regex_match( argv_1, std::basic_regex< char >
( "s?([/|@#])(?:(?!\\1).)+\\1(?:(?!\\1).)*\\1(?:(?:gi?|ig)?(?:\\1-?[1-9]\\d?)?|i)?" ) );
```

The Problem:
Although the pattern is **non-greedy**; on Windows it becomes **greedy** and matches more then 4 delimiters. Therefore it should not match `/one/two/three/four/five/` but this string is matched!

---

NOTE:

- I deliberately have dropped `^` and `$` assertions since in the C++ regex the `std::regex_match` by default has them and it no need to use them
- Also the two backslashes `\\`; one of them is escape character
- javescript code says `no`

```js
const regex = /^s?([/|@#])(?:(?!\1).)+\1(?:(?!\1).)*\1((?:gi?|gi)\1-?[1-9]\d|i)?$/gm;
var str = 's/one/two/gi/-33/';
if( str.match( regex ) ){
  console.log( "okay" );
} else {
  console.log( "no" );
}
```

- Perl also says `no`, as you can see in the screenshot, but c++ says `okay`

### [image]

Does someone know why it becomes greedy?

Thanks.

Comment: on Windows but what compiler?

Comment: both `g++` and the same options

Comment: GCC 6.3 on Unix - https://ideone.com/lKEh1S - says  "no". Looks like the GCC must be updated on your machine.

Comment: You know, the only "tangible" advice I have seen in these cases is "switch" to Boost regex library.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oh I tested it and you made a mistake the output of `gcc 6.3.0` is correct and say **no** .....  I am familiar with *boost** and my program works fine on Linux but I wanted to test it on Windows since it uses **standard library**

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew [You can see here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/7JDG0GLu4476V7Cv) with `gcc 6.3.0` and says **no** but if you take away the last delimiter `/` then it say **okay**

Comment: That string you tested just [does not match](https://regex101.com/r/E82iQC/1) the regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes it should not match that because it has more than 4 delimiters. It should match `s/.//gi/33` but should not match `s/.//gi/33/` please notice at regex that I have. It controls the number of delimiter that are between **2 up to 4** not more not less or see my previous question that I liked above in the question. Also I am sorry since my English writing is not very good.

Comment: Which version of gcc are you running on windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to have been a bug in GCC that got fixed in version 5.4. My guess is you are running an older version on your Windows set-up.

See the difference in output in:

- [Version 4.9](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/7OQU0SwzilD73tks): "okey" (wrong)
- [Version 5.4](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/KTLrGKB7LsZBkz9z): "no" (right)

It does not seem to make a difference whether `boost` is included or not.

The bug is related to `(?!\\1)`, as replacing it by `(?![/])` (in both instances) solves the issue, but obviously that would limit the regular expression for use with the `/` delimiter only:

- [Version 4.9 with `(?![1])`](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/qSzNtvBS0JJiVhRy): "no" (correct)

Also, the bug appears with this simple regular expression: `(.)((?!\\1).)` which should reject an input like `aa`:

- [Version 5.4](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/BUqyGgV35qdkaB2r): "no" (right)
- [Version 4.9](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/L9THbDkT54dr10hx): "okey" (wrong)

Conclusion: make sure to install GCC version 5.4 or higher.

Comment: Very very thanks. I was upset that my program had problem. Unfortunately I used `gcc 5.3.0` on Windows and I could not update it to `6.2.0` from source.  I blamed `gcc` myself but I was not sure that such a bug even exist on `gcc`.