# Why does this code works in visual studio but fails in gcc?

Tags: c++, regex

This code compiles and run (Parsing backtrace_symbols)

In gcc I get "regex_error" exception on call to regex_match
while in VS2017 it doesnt?!?

```
const std::regex r( R"(\((\w*)\+\w*\)\s+\[(\w+)\])");
std::smatch m;
const bool bMatch = std::regex_match(curStr,m,r);
```

Can someone explain?

Comment: GCC (stdlibc++) and <regex> never really worked too well, what version are you using?

Comment: @DeiDei, Never? It's been implemented for a while now and [works on trunk](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qyPSFvU8L2NCKE0z).

Comment: @chris Bad choice of word on my part. I meant there's been numerous questions on SO about this. That's why I asked for the version the OP is using.

Comment: Seems that this also happens with Intel Compiler (icpc). I finally overcome this using boost::regex instead of std::regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug up to version `4.8.5`

## [You can see it here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jLKlboPoRH6O2VT6)

I even found some bug up to version `5.3.0`
So I suggest you at least use version `5.4.0` or **upper** with gcc

[See a bug in version `5.3.0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42627957/the-same-regex-but-different-results-on-linux-and-windows-only-c)