# Fail to match with negative look-ahead assertion when tracking down on a delimiter

Tags: d

As long as I know a little about RegExp, the two below patterns are the same:

```
`^(?:[ab]|ab)(.)(?:(?!\1).)+\1$`

`^(?:ab|[ab])(.)(?:(?!\1).)+\1$`
```

but the number [ 1 ] is **false** and the [ 2 ] is **true**, whereas it should be true for both:

---

code:

```
void main( immutable string[] args ){

    immutable string str = "ab some-word ";
    Regex!( char ) rx = regex( `^(?:[ab]|ab)(.)(?:(?!\1).)+\1$` );
    immutable bool     b1 = !matchFirst( str, rx ).empty();

    writeln( b1 );  // false ( should be true )

    rx = regex( `^(?:ab|[ab])(.)(?:(?!\1).)+\1$` );
    immutable bool     b2 = !matchFirst( str, rx ).empty();

    writeln( b2 );  // true

}
```

---

[Demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/JV9Ju1/1)

the main problem is not related to character class [], since the following is true for both:

```
^(?:ab|[ab])(.)-\1$

^(?:[ab]|ab)(.)-\1$
```

but with: `(.)(?:(?!\1).)` it fails if a character-class appears at the beginning.

I am not sure but may it is the same bug that GCC below the version 5.3.0 have had.

here is my question and found out this bug:
[the same regex but different results on Linux and Windows only C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42627957/the-same-regex-but-different-results-on-linux-and-windows-only-c)

Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: **dmd --version** `DMD32 D Compiler v2.074.0`