# std regex_search to match only current line

Tags: c++, regex, parsing, stl

I use a various regexes to parse a C source file, line by line. First i read all the content of file in a string:

```
ifstream file_stream("commented.cpp",ifstream::binary);

std::string txt((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file_stream)),
std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

Then i use a set of regex, which should be applied continusly until the match found, here i will give only one for example:

```
vector<regex> rules = { regex("^//[^\n]*$") };

char * search =(char*)txt.c_str();

int position = 0, length = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < rules.size(); i++) {
  cmatch match;

  if (regex_search(search + position, match, rules[i],regex_constants::match_not_bol | regex_constants::match_not_eol)) 
  {
     position += ( match.position() + match.length() );        
  }

}
```

But it don't work. It will match the comment not in the current line, but it will search whole string, for the first match, `regex_constants::match_not_bol` and  `regex_constants::match_not_eol` should make the `regex_search` to recognize `^$` as start/end of line only, not end start/end of whole block. So here is my file:

**commented.cpp:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
//comment
```

The code should fail, my logic is with those options to regex_search, the match should fail, because it should search for pattern in the first line:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

But instead it searches whole string, and immideatly finds `//comment`. I need help, to make `regex_search` match only in current line. The options `match_not_bol` and `match_not_eol` do not help me. Of course i can read a file line by line in a vector, and then do match of all rules on each string in vector, but it is very slow, i have done that, and it take too long time to parse a big file like that, that's why i want to let regex deal with new lines, and use positioning counter.

Comment: Why to to read file into vector of strings? Then applying regex to current line will be easy.

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky i done it, and it work very very slow. 2 minute to process file of 3000 C code strings

Comment: So you have a version of the code that works fast and does not do the work. And another version of the code that does what you want but works slowly? I recommend - to ask another question - show the properly working version of your code and ask how to make it faster.

Comment: You might be seeing the effects of CRLF (two chars) v LF (standard Unix) since you are opening the file in binary mode.

Comment: Can accept a suggestion about `std::regex` library. I have no code for you but I can explain what is going on for you

Answer (score 1):

> If it is not what you want please comment so I will delete the answer

What you are doing is not a correct way of using a regex library.
Thus here is my suggestion for anyone that wants to use `std::regex` library.

1. It only supports `ECMAScript` that somehow is a little
   poor than all modern `regex` library.
2. It has bugs as many as you like ( just I found ):

   1. [the same regex but different results on Linux and Windows only C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42627957/the-same-regex-but-different-results-on-linux-and-windows-only-c)
   2. [std::regex and ignoring flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44735201/stdregex-and-ignoring-flags)
   3. [std::regex_match and lazy quantifier with strange behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422778/stdregex-match-and-lazy-quantifier-with-strange-behavior)
3. In some cases (I test specifically with `std::match_results` ) It is **200** times slower in comparison to `std.regex` in [d](/questions/tagged/d) language
4. It has very confusing `flag-match` and almost it does not work (at least for me)

conclusion: do not use it at all.

---

But if anyone still demands to use [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) anyway then you can:

1. use `boost::regex` <sup>[about Boost library](http://www.regular-expressions.info/boost.html)</sup> because:

   1. It is `PCRE` support
   2. It has less bug ( I have not seen any )
   3. It is smaller in **bin** file ( I mean executable file after compiling )
   4. It is faster then `std::regex`
2. use `gcc version 7.1.0` and **NOT** below. The last bug I found is in version `6.3.0`
3. use `clang version 3` or above

---

If you have enticed (= persuade) to **NOT** use [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) then you can use:

1. Use [d](/questions/tagged/d) regular expression <sup>[link](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_regex.html)</sup> library for large task: `std.regex` and why:

   1. Fast <sup>[Faster Command Line Tools in D](https://dlang.org/blog/2017/05/24/faster-command-line-tools-in-d/)</sup>
   2. Easy
   3. Flexible <sup>[drn](https://github.com/k-five/dren)</sup>
2. Use native `pcre` or `pcre2` <sup>[link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/pcre.html)</sup> that have been written in [c](/questions/tagged/c)

   - Extremely fast but a little complicated
3. Use [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) for a simple task and specially **Perl one-liner** <sup>[link](https://github.com/k-five/illustrated_Perl_one-liners)</sup>

Comment: I will try boost and  reply to you

Answer (score 0):

> `#include <stdio.h>
>   //comment`
>
> The code should fail, my logic is with those options to regex_search, the match should fail, because it should search for pattern in the first line:
>
> `#include <stdio.h>`
>
> But instead it searches whole string, and immideatly finds //comment. I need help, to make regex_search match only in current line.

Are you trying to match all `//` comments in a source code file, or only the first line?

The former can be done like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
  auto input = std::ifstream{"stream_union.h"};

  for(auto line = std::string{}; getline(input, line); )
  {
    auto submatch = std::smatch{};
    auto pattern = std::regex(R"(//)");
    std::regex_search(line, submatch, pattern);

    auto match = submatch.str(0);
    if(match.empty()) continue;

    std::cout << line << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And the later can be done like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
  auto input = std::ifstream{"stream_union.h"};
  auto line = std::string{};
  getline(input, line);

  auto submatch = std::smatch{};
  auto pattern = std::regex(R"(//)");
  std::regex_search(line, submatch, pattern);

  auto match = submatch.str(0);
  if(match.empty()) { return EXIT_FAILURE; }

  std::cout << line << std::endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If for any reason you're trying to get the position of the match, tellg() will do that for you.

Comment: I'm trying to match all source file, to divide it by logical tokens. Tha'ts why i need to process line by line, i included only regex for comment to explain what is problem. But really i have a set of regex, each one designed to match an include/identifier/operator of the C source code. I need to do the search of all those regexes on each line, to do code tokenizing. What i do is a work, that compiler does, when parse source file.

Comment: You can't parse C with regex.  You can token out individual words, but you can't parse most of the language without more tools than just regex.


It should be plenty fast to run a dozen regexes on a single line of code at a time.  The example I wrote above regexes a single line, not the entire source code at once.  This should speed things up quite a bit.


And for any reason if you need it even faster, re2 is the fastest c++ regex library (that I know of), but for basic tokenization you shouldn't notice a difference. It is the size of the input into the regex that determines the speed.