# regex_replace matches end of string twice

Tags: c++, regex

Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (argc==4)
    std::cout << std::regex_replace(
        argv[1], std::regex(argv[2]), argv[3]
      ) << std::endl;
}
```

Running

```
./a.out a_a_a '[^_]+$' b
```

gives the expected result `a_a_b`. But running

```
./a.out a_a_a '[^_]*$' b
```

prints `a_a_bb`.

`boost::regex_replace` has the same behavior.

I don't understand why the empty string after the last `a` gets matched again, when I've already consumed `$`.

Comment: I think it is because of `*`. Since it maches 0 or 1, thus first maches nothing and put a **b** and then maches that b and puts the second **b**. Make sure you are using gcc 7.1.0 or clang 3.0 or higher

Comment: It is a known behavior for a lot of regex flavors. If you want to match *something* make sure your pattern does not match an empty string. Or at least anchor both at start and end.

Comment: Can someone explain the rational for this design? I fail to see how `$` serves it's role, if there's still something left to match after it's consumed.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple difference between `*` quantifier and `+` quantifier. The `*` matches the end letter `a` as well as a zero-width at the end.

You can see it here:

### [`[^_]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/1X2WVS/2)

Not only it matches the last `a` but also matches the zero-width after that, and thus the result would be `a_a_bb`

---

For being sure about how it works in this way try:

### `[^_]*`

and if you feed the program `a_a_a` the output would be:

`bb_bb_bb`

### [`[^_]*`](https://regex101.com/r/1X2WVS/3)

---

Note that the pattern `[^_]` matches all three `a`s but as soon as you put an asterisk `*` after this pattern, it makes the pattern: **matches a single a or nothing (= zero-width)** and thus the pattern `[^_]*` against the subject `a_a_a` matches **6** points: `a` and between `a` and `_` and so on.

```
a_a_a
^^^^^^
```

Comment: My misunderstanding was in that I thought that for `.*` to match *nothing*, that *nothing* had to be in a place that's not immediately after *something* this same pattern had just matched. That's how `sed` behaves.

Comment: `sed 's/[^_]*$/b/' <<< a_a_a` prints `a_a_b`.

Comment: There is a lot of regex flavor and `sed` supports basic(s) not a rich-flexible. [SEE my answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087665/std-regex-search-to-match-only-current-line/46098368#46098368) about C++ regex library

Answer (score 1):

Anchors don't get consumed (since they are 0-width).

You could try making the pattern `abc$$$` to match the string `abc` and it will still match, as would the pattern `^^^abc`. Thus, the `$` in your function doesn't get consumed, and allows both `a$` and `(empty)$` to match.

Answer (score 0):

I think because

```
+ means 1 or many (at least one occurrence for the match to succeed)
* means 0 or many (the match succeeds regardless of the presence of the search string)
```

So, `[^_]+$` matches only a while `[^_]*$` matches a and empty-character, so it makes a double `b`.